# How Connect sortable with different class div

Tags: jquery

I have problem with connected sortable div-s. When I drag item from first sortable div to another sortable div, it works. Problem occurs when I drag it on second sortable, but don't drop it, instead I tried move back item to first sortable div, it moves to second sortable instead of first sortable.
here is my jquery, i can't find way to solve this problem.. Here is basic jquery code for connected sortables, which I have used in my code:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable1" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable2",
        revert: false
    }); 
    $( ".sortable2" ).sortable({

    });

    $( ".sortable1,.sortable2" ).disableSelection();
});
```

And finnaly example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KtpJj/3/
Any suggestions??

**Update:** When I change my jquery code like this, another problem occurs...

```
$(function() {
  $( ".sortable1" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable2",
    revert: false
  }); 
  $( ".sortable2" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable1",
    revert: false
  });

$( ".sortable1,.sortable2" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Is it possible to deny dragging back from second div to first? For that I have to remove form last jquery code { connectWith: ".sortable1" }.  but in this case, when I will drag items from first div to second without dropping them on second, after instead of dropping it on second div if I will drag it away from first and second div, it will return to second, but it have to return to the first div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `sortable` for the second one also:

```
$( ".sortable2" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable1",
    revert: false
});
```

Also you need to disable [overflowing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) from these *divs*, so I've added the following definitions to your CSS:

```
.sortable1 { overflow: hidden; }
.sortable2 { overflow: hidden; }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KtpJj/7/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And one more question. Is it possible to deny dragging back from second div to first? I think for that I have to remove { connectWith: ".sortable1" } from your code, but in this case, when I will drag items from first div to second without dropping them on second, after instead of dropping it on second div if I will drag it away from first and second div, it will return to second, but it have to return to first div.